# Registry version wrong

Tags: windows, registry, directx, directx-9

I want to read the DirectX version from Registry.

I found the value at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DirectX under the value Version.

My problem: Refering to [Hey Scripting Guy!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/01/08/how-can-i-determine-the-version-of-directx-installed-on-a-computer.aspx) my version "4.09.00.0904" is 9.0c, but dxdiag shows DirectX 11.

How to find the right version? Or is there probably a way to solve this without the registry?

EDIT:
I'm using Windows 7 Professional x86

Comment: no, I used the Command Prompt as Administrator.

Comment: I meant you could check DX version using `dxdiag`.

Comment: no, I want to use it in a c++ program.

Comment: Ah. You should mention that and tag it so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't detect any version above DirectX 9 from the registry. It's simply not stored in there.

For versions 10 and above, you should use the COM interface to DXDiag.

1. Instantiate a DXDiagProvider (CoCreateInstance(
   CLSID_DxDiagProvider, ... IID_IDxDiagProvider, ... )
2. Initialize it (pDxDiagProvider->Initialize)
3. Open the root container (pDxDiagProvider->GetRootContainer)
4. Open the child container DxDiag_SystemInfo (rootContainer->GetChildContainer(L"DxDiag_SystemInfo", ...)
5. Read the variant (VT_UI4) properties `dwDirectXVersionMajor` and `dwDirectXVersionMajor` (systemInfo->GetProp( ... ))
6. If relevant, read the VT_BSTR property `szDirectXVersionLetter` as well.

Inconvenient? Very. Write once, wrap in a utility function, never look back. Or copy-paste one of the [common implementations.](http://code.ohloh.net/search?s=getdxver.cpp&browser=Default&pp=0&fl=C%2B%2B&ff=1&filterChecked=true&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1)

Comment: is there a way to find it out of the registry?

Comment: Note that the DxDiagProvider is also kinda slow and takes 2-4 seconds for me to query the information.

Comment: DxDiagProvider enumerating all children and their properties - https://gist.github.com/lihas/ef6b9fa16fe26bd472940f6fd2fa4623